# How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

How do I get the current Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android using location tools?

Answer (score 355):

Use the [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

The call to `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't block - which means it will return `null` if no position is currently available - so you probably want to have a look at passing a [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to the [`requestLocationUpdates()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead, which will give you asynchronous updates of your location.

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

You'll need to give your application the [`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) if you want to use GPS.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You may also want to add the [`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) for when GPS isn't available and select your location provider with the [`getBestProvider()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider(android.location.Criteria,%20boolean)).

Comment: will this works in emulator. did this code shows lati and longi in the emulator???????

Comment: You should also be sure to remove the updates in onPause (or where needed) in order to stop getting updates you no longer want. -> lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);

Comment: How accurate is getLastLocation?

Comment: Your link to LocationManager return 404

Comment: If you're already using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, you implicitly have coarse location permission enabled:

"If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers."
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: is it necessary that mobile data should be enabled?

Comment: I used this code and the nedded permissions but longitude and latitude are null..where is the error here?

Answer (score 42):

Here is the class `LocationFinder` to find the GPS location. This class will call `MyLocation`, which will do the business.

**LocationFinder**

```
public class LocationFinder extends Activity {

    int increment = 4;
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();

    // private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intermediat);
        myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(), locationResult);

        boolean r = myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(),
            locationResult);

        startActivity(new Intent(LocationFinder.this,
        // Nearbyhotelfinder.class));
            GPSMyListView.class));
        finish();
    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double Latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Location",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                SharedPreferences locationpref = getApplication()
                    .getSharedPreferences("location", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = locationpref.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("Longitude", Longitude + "");
                prefsEditor.putString("Latitude", Latitude + "");
                prefsEditor.commit();
                System.out.println("SHARE PREFERENCE ME PUT KAR DIYA.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    // handler for the background updating

}
```

**MyLocation**

```
public class MyLocation {

    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //Toast.makeText(context, gps_enabled+" "+network_enabled,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();


        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 10000);
    //    Toast.makeText(context, " Yaha Tak AAya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override

        public void run() {

            //Context context = getClass().getgetApplicationContext();
             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work man..!!! above code was not working but your code is working fine,,!! Strange why people didn't what you!.. thnks

Comment: @sandy this comment is aweomse 
Toast.makeText(context, " Yaha Tak AAya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

+1

Comment: @sandy yeah. how to get the latitude and longitude from this. Sorry for this silly question

Comment: Finally found the best solution to my problem with getting the latitude and longitude from inside of gotLocation. Shared preferences solved it. Thank you!

Comment: @rup35h You are missing something!  ( System.out.println("SHARE PREFERENCE ME PUT KAR DIYA."); ) +1

Answer (score 21):

With `google` things changes very often: non of the previous answers worked for me.

based on [this google training](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) here is how you do it using

> fused location provider

this requires Set Up Google Play Services

**Activity class**

```
public class GPSTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,     
 GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            setResult(1,intent);
            finish();

        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

**usage**

in you activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, GPSTrackerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

And this method

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Double longitude = extras.getDouble("Longitude");
        Double latitude = extras.getDouble("Latitude");
    }
}
```

Comment: And declare the Activity in AndroidManifest xml file

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Android Studio takes care of this step for you now.

Comment: startActivityForResult(intent,1); is depracated now

Answer (score 10):

you can got Current latlng using this

`

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private String provider;
  private MyLocationListener mylistener;
  private Criteria criteria;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


             locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
              criteria = new Criteria();
              criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);   //default

              // user defines the criteria

              criteria.setCostAllowed(false); 
              // get the best provider depending on the criteria
              provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

              // the last known location of this provider
              Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

              mylistener = new MyLocationListener();

              if (location != null) {
                  mylistener.onLocationChanged(location);
              } else {
                  // leads to the settings because there is no last known location
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
              // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200millsecs change
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, mylistener);
            String a=""+location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, 222).show();

}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Initialize the location fields



          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  ""+location.getLatitude()+location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  

      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, provider + "'s status changed to "+status +"!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " enabled!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " disabled!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 5):

Above solutions is also correct, but some time if location is null then it crash the app or not working properly. The best way to get Latitude and Longitude of android is:

```
 Geocoder geocoder;
     String bestProvider;
     List<Address> user = null;
     double lat;
     double lng;

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
     Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

     if (location == null){
         Toast.makeText(activity,"Location Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }else{
        geocoder = new Geocoder(activity);
        try {
            user = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        lat=(double)user.get(0).getLatitude();
        lng=(double)user.get(0).getLongitude();
        System.out.println(" DDD lat: " +lat+",  longitude: "+lng);

        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What names space are all of these classes in?

Answer (score 2):

**Best way is**

Add permission manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then you can get GPS location or if GPS location is not available then this function return NETWORK location

```
    public static Location getLocationWithCheckNetworkAndGPS(Context mContext) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    assert lm != null;
    isGpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkLocationEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    Location networkLoacation = null, gpsLocation = null, finalLoc = null;
    if (isGpsEnabled)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return null;
        }gpsLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isNetworkLocationEnabled)
        networkLoacation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (gpsLocation != null && networkLoacation != null) {

        //smaller the number more accurate result will
        if (gpsLocation.getAccuracy() > networkLoacation.getAccuracy())
            return finalLoc = networkLoacation;
        else
            return finalLoc = gpsLocation;

    } else {

        if (gpsLocation != null) {
            return finalLoc = gpsLocation;
        } else if (networkLoacation != null) {
            return finalLoc = networkLoacation;
        }
    }
    return finalLoc;
}
```

Comment: Please share your internet and gps state checker function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)**

For using Fused Location Provider in your project you will have to add the **google play services location** dependency in our app level **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   ...
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

**Permissions in Manifest**

Apps that use location services must request location permissions. Android offers two location permissions: *ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION* and *ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION*.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

As you may know that from Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) you must request permissions for important access in the runtime. Cause it’s a security issue where while installing an application, user may not clearly understand about an important permission of their device.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this,
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
    PERMISSION_ID
)
```

Then you can use the FusedLocationProvider Client to get the updated location in your desired place.

```
    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        var location: Location? = task.result
        if (location == null) {
            requestNewLocationData()
        } else {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = location.latitude.toString()
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = location.longitude.toString()
        }
    }
```

You can also check certain configuration like if the device has location settings on or not. You can also check the article on [Detect Current Latitude & Longitude using Kotlin in Android](https://blog.frsarker.com/kotlin/detect-current-latitude-and-longitude-using-kotlin-in-android.html) for more functionality.
If there is no cache location then it will catch the current location using:

```
private fun requestNewLocationData() {
    var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
    mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    mLocationRequest.interval = 0
    mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
    mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plug and play location-manager that can be used both in XML-based projects and Jetpack Compose projects (personally using it in JetpackCompose)

```
class LocationManager(context: Context): LocationCallback() {

val context = context
var publicCompletion: ((Double, Double) -> Unit)? = null

var fusedLocationProviderClient = FusedLocationProviderClient(
    context
)

fun requestLocationPermission() {
    val activity = context as Activity?
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        activity!!,
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ),
        101
    )
}

fun checkIfLocationPermissionIsGranted(): Boolean {
    return (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            )
}

fun getLatitudeLongitude(completion: (Double, Double) -> Unit) {
    publicCompletion = { latitude, longitude ->
        completion(latitude, longitude)
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        val activity = context as Activity?
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(activity!!) { task ->
            var location: Location? = task.result
            if (location != null) {
                publicCompletion?.let { it(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude) }
            } else {
                requestLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    var request = LocationRequest()
    request.priority = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    request.fastestInterval = 0
    request.numUpdates = 1

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            request, this, Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }
}

override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
    super.onLocationResult(p0)

    publicCompletion?.let { it(p0!!.lastLocation!!.latitude, p0!!.lastLocation!!.longitude) }
}

override fun onLocationAvailability(p0: LocationAvailability?) {
    super.onLocationAvailability(p0)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow Google recommendation and prepared codes in kotlin: (Supports also Android 11 and 12):

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/while-in-use-location

and its step by step explanation:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/while-in-use-location

[image]