# get the current location (gps/wifi)

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to get my location using it like this:

```
LocationManager myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); 
criteria.setBearingRequired(false); 
criteria.setCostAllowed(true); 
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 

String provider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true); 

if (provider != null) { 
    //there is a provider
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10L, 500.0f, (LocationListener) mainContext);
    Location myCurLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
            //here i'm trying to get some data from the
            //myCurLocation but 
            //myCurLocation == NULL
}
```

but the myCurLocation is always == NULL

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't block - which means it will return `null` if no position is currently available - so you probably want to have a look at passing a [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to the [`requestLocationUpdates()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead, which will give you asynchronous updates of your location.

Have a look at [this question for an example of using a `LocationListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android).