# Android Position reset after Restart? -> Serious Problem

Tags: android, gps, location, nullpointerexception

is it possible, that android cleares the last known location after a restart?
Yesterday my code worked very fine, but today after rebooting my phone (AND emulator) it seems that the .getLastKnownLocation (see below) returns null, which leads to a nullPointerException...
Can you confirm that?
How can I avoid this problem? I'm desperately searching for an answer

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

...

```
Location locUser = lm
    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
posUser = new GeoPoint((int) (locUser.getLatitude() * 1E6),
(int) (locUser.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

Would be great if someone coult give me a hint or point out my mistake.

Nice greetings, Poeschlorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't block - which means it will return `null` if no position is currently available, which is very likely after a device restart.  I would be surprised if Android caches the current location when a user switches a device off since it is likely that the device will move before it is switched back on again.

You'll need to pass a [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to the [`requestLocationUpdates()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead, which will give you asynchronous updates of your location.

Have a look at [this question for an example of using a `LocationListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android).

Comment: hi dave,
what you pointed out seems to be logical ;-)
I already implemented a working Locationlistener, but it updates just ervery 1-5 sec (param).
how can I tell it to refresh before the code above is beeing executed?

Comment: I don't think you can force it to refresh.  The call doesn't block so if GPS is taking a while to get a lock the getLastKnownLocation() will return `null` and your app will have to handle this situation.