# Gsm Network Parameters in android

Tags: android

is it possible to get the following parameters in android programmatically.
"
Ø  Rx Level (Receive Signal Strength)

Ø  Tx Level

Ø  Serving PN

Ø  LAT/LONG Co-ordinates

Ø  SINR

Ø  DRC

Ø  Ec/Io

Ø  C/I

Ø  Channel Number

Ø  Layer-3 Messaging

Ø  HTTP/FTP Measurements

"

Comment: I searched a bit and here you can at least find some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Ø Rx Level (Receive Signal Strength)
Yes, see Android SDK, the class: CellSignalStrength

Ø Tx Level
No, It's impossible

Ø Serving PN
For GSM, we can get the LAC, CI, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html

Ø LAT/LONG Co-ordinates
Yes, Just get it via GPS

Ø SINR
Yes, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthCdma.html#getEvdoSnr()

Ø DRC
No, It's impossible

Ø Ec/Io
Yes, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthCdma.html

Ø C/I
No, it's impossible

Ø Channel Number
No, it's impossible

Ø Layer-3 Messaging
No for all models, only available for some specify model with Qualcomm Chipset with ROOT permission.

Ø HTTP/FTP Measurements
Yes. But you need to do the FTP/HTTP yourself.