# Android Google Maps - getLastKnownLocation returns inaccurate latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I am developing an app where I need to calculate the distance from the current position and some other locations. I am using the GPS to access the users current location and the other locations coordinates are stored in a database. The problem occurs in the following snippet:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    Log.v("LOCATION LAT", String.valueOf(arg0.getLatitude()));
    currentLocation = arg0; //currentLocation is a global class variable
}
```

The problem is when I feed the DDMS with coordinates such as:
Latitude: 62.639579
Longitude: 17.909689 and log these values I get Latitude: 62.0 and Longitude 17.0 .

If I create a location object and set the lat and lng values myself it works. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    Location current = new Location("Current location");
    current.setLatitude(62.639579);
    current.setLongitude(17.909689);
    Log.v("Current LAT", "" + current.getLatitude());
}
```

**EDIT SOLVED:**

Found the problem. I was feeding the the DDMS with faulty formatting. Apparently this should be delimited with a comma sign, not a dot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was feeding the the DDMS with faulty formatting. Apparently the coordinates should be delimited with a comma sign, not a dot...

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the permissions specified in this post? Else it kicks back to using cell tower triangulation.
[Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android)

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for fast response. The minute I posted the question I found the problem :P See solution above.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like as below. Create a location variable in that you have to assign location change var

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    Location current = new Location("Current location");
    current=arg0;
    Log.v("Current LAT", "" + current.getLatitude());
}
```