# How to get the current latitude and longitude in my mobile

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I have developed an application which uses Google's API Level 8, when I run the app in my device supporting Android Version 2.2 , It is working properly, I can also  get my current latitude and longitude.But when I run the same application on the device has Android version 2.3.4 then it works ok except one thing that I am not able to get my current latitude and longitude, it returns null value.

How to make my app compatible with all version of Android , is there a way or its a bug in Android API level , I have stucked here your help will be highy obliged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2227299/1007273

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobiledevice in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Other Option you can use Phonegap in your android application..please follow the link [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/start/)