# Using Location Services on a custom map

Tags: java, android, dictionary

So we have a custom map of an area and we want to use location services to locate the position of the user. The only concern is that it will not be in sync with the map we have, and using google maps is not an option. Is there any way to use location services in favor of our map? Or any other idea you may have that could help us?

TL;DR need to track users location on custom map, not using GMaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant answer, but if you refer to [How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android), use the latitude and longitude from the GPS unit and map it to your map, you should end up with a fairly workable solution.