# How to get lat and longtitude values out from google places details result

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have successfully returns result of a place details with the code below:

```
private PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String url) throws Exception{


        String jsonResults =null;
        HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper();
        try {
            jsonResults = helper.GetJSonString(url);
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results

             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString()).getJSONObject("result");

             placeDetails = new PlaceDetails();
             placeDetails.setName(jsonObj.getString("name"));
             placeDetails.setFormatted_address(jsonObj.getString("formatted_address"));
             placeDetails.setInternational_phone_number(jsonObj.getString("international_phone_number"));



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error processing JSON results " + e.getMessage().toString(), e);
        }

        return placeDetails;
    }
```

Now, my problem is I dont know how to get lat and lng values out of the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251023/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In your response you get lat lon

```
"geometry" : {
     "location" : {
       "lat" : -33.8669710,
       "lng" : 151.1958750
     }
```

you only have to parse the data using JsonArray like this

jsonObj.getJsonArray("geometry");

you can refer this link http://yuvislm.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/google-places-api-and-json-parsing-in-android/    for the complete code

Comment: I have used this code JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
         
          
 String lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObj1.get("result")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
            .getJSONObject("location").getString("lat"); but its not still working.

Answer (score 0):

You have parse response as follw

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
JSONObject result =jsonObj.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
Double longitude  = result.getDouble("lng");
Double latitude =  result.getDouble("lat");
```

As you will get response like

```
"geometry" : {
     "location" : {
       "lat" : -33.8669710,
       "lng" : 151.1958750
     }
```

To see response Details

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults