# How to find the current longitude and latitude value automatically?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am trying to make one app which will give the nearest hospital name and address. I am using Json parsing. Here is my code ..

I am using this url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4367624,78.439968799&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAwBKDflSlg9d38GX1xrwpnwcbWCzdVj-A"

I this longi and lati value is given manually but i want that where ever user will go, it should take the corresponding lat & long value according to the current location. Please help me how can i approach this...Any help will be appreciable.. Thank you..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    JSONArray jsonArray;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4367624,78.439968799&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAwBKDflSlg9d38GX1xrwpnwcbWCzdVj-A");
        north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        List_Adapter la = new List_Adapter();
        list.setAdapter(la);
    }

    class List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return jsonArray.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int index, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            try {
                tv.append("id : "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("id")
                                .toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("level: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("level")
                                .toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("time_in_secs: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index)
                                .getString("time_in_secs").toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("par: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("par")
                                .toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("initials: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("initials")
                                .toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("quote: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("quote")
                                .toString() + "\n");
                tv.append("time_stamp: "
                        + jsonArray.getJSONObject(index)
                                .getString("time_stamp").toString() + "\n");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return v;
        }

    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(rLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android

Even though its for a different purpose, you are simply trying to get longitude and latitude of phone. The link was the first google hit and seems pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

If you follow it you will receive location updates and can put it in the request string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to get the Current location details for more details Follow [android developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).There you have full document about location aware.

**First Specify App Permissions in manifest to access current loaction**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Code to retrieve the Current Location**

```
LocationManager locationManager;
double current_latitude,current_longitude;
String location_context;
Location location;
double[] find_Location() {

    location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(location_context);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    for (String provider : providers) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
            new LocationListener() {

                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {}
            });
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
            current_longitude = location.getLongitude();

        }
    }
    return new double[]{current_latitude,current_longitude};
}
```