# Not getting the real latitude and longitude? Only getting 0.0 0.0

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-geocoder

Here I am using this code in order to get the latitude and longitude of the location but all that I am getting is latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0 the code to find the latitude and logitude that I am using is given as below , Also I am testing this code in Genymotion emulator and all that is printed in the log is  0.0 0.0 because the if(address.size()>0) is not getting satisfyied can anyone tell where am I going wrong or is it because of emulator.

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getActivity());
            try {
                List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocationName(str_ELocation,1);
                if (address.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d("List Size : ", "" + address.size());
                    latitude = address.get(0).getLatitude();
                    longitude = address.get(0).getLongitude();
                } else {
                    Log.d("In Else", "In Else");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("LONGITUDE AND LATITUDE", "" + longitude + "" + latitude);
```

Also is there any other simpler solution to just find latitude and longitude. I am using this in Fragment and so I am using getActivity() here instead of myClassName.this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have a backend service you are using to obtain this information.

**Note** [The Docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

> The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in
>   the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an
>   empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the
>   isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation
>   exists.

This should also be done on a background `Thread` if not already being done.

### Alternative

You may be better off using [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Be sure to read those docs on it before beginning to have an understanding of how it works and should be implemented (That portion is short).

[Here is an example that can get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android)

Anything like this should be done on a background `Thread` and not on the `UI Thread`. And there are listeners which can return the values you need.

*full disclosure: I haven't used GPS but I read through the docs ;)*

Comment: Sure not an issue at least you tried thanks for that and yes will try the same with location manager. Thanks codeMagic :).\

Comment: Which part is not an issue? I don't see anywhere that you are requesting results. The `Geocoder` class itself does not already have the info. It has to retrieve it from a backend service.

Comment: Yep and in the exception it was displaying that service not available when I was running it in the Samsung Star Duos

Comment: @GauravADubey then that's the problem. Use `LocationManager` instead.

Comment: Yep Roger That.. Its getting too late so will be trying it tomorrow with another live device.. with LocationManager. Will update you soon.