# Giving a button Default clicked

Tags: android, button

Hello I am having a problem. I am having three buttons in a view and whenever the view is loaded then all the three buttons are displayed but none of the button is shown in clicked as default. What I want to do is that when that view is loaded I want the first of the three buttons to be shown in clicked form and its data shown in the listview below it.. Can someone please help...

This is my Layout where I have three Buttons and a listview each button has a list to be displayed in listview. This Page is loaded after Splash Screen and what I want is the first button to show the list associated with it in listview when the page loads the each time.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calender_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimention_of_background_of_button"
        android:background="#06960F"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nearby_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimention_of_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_nearby_selected"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myevent_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimention_of_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@drawable/btn_myevents"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fav_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimention_of_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_favorite"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Eventlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calender_layout" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/cal_footer_layout">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cal_footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#06960F"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Searchspinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_selection_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="#06960F"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EnterDataToSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You will need to provide relevant code. But it sounds like you want a [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html). Possibly a [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) which `extends CompoundButton`

Comment: posting code will be more easy to answer

Comment: ok posting it by editing in a minute..

Comment: Please see the editted question also please do inform if more clarification is needed friends :)

Comment: Your Java code is more relevant but I still suggest using `CompoundButtons`. It has the functionality you are looking for by default

Comment: ok sure let me have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short example of what I mean from comments.

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/typeGroup"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="3">
            <ToggleButton 
                android:id="@+id/hotBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                style="@style/HotButtonSmall"/> 
            <ToggleButton 
                android:id="@+id/coldBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/ColdButtonSmall"/>
            <ToggleButton 
                android:id="@+id/frozenBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/FrozenButtonSmall"/>
   </RadioGroup>
```

I have them in a `RadioGroup` so only one will be checked at a time. My `styles` just set certain icons for the state they are in. `android:checked="true"` on the first button sets it to checked when the layout loads.

### Remove text (if you want)

In my `styles.xml` I have

```
<item name="android:textOff"></item>
<item name="android:textOn"></item>
```

for each corresponding style so that it doesn't show "Off"/"On" when the states change.

### Click event

Since these are in a `RadioGroup`, I use

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
```

to trigger necessary code when a button is pressed instead of an `onClick()`

[CompoundButton Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)

**Edit**

To simply use a normal button and have it "clicked" when you first load the `Activity`, you can simply do

```
firstBtn.performClick();  //assuming firstBtn is the name of the button you want clicked
```

inside `onCreate()` after you have initialized the buttons. You will have to set up a state selector to change how the buttons looked when they are pressed/clicked or not.

Comment: Yes you got the point but I am having simple button friend and not toggle button.

Comment: Yes, friend, but I was trying to explain an easier way to achieve the "look and feel" of what you want. Anyway, I have edited with a way to do what you want with your buttons.

Comment: You're welcome. So did you figure something out, then?

Comment: can you help me with this one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578724/not-getting-the-real-latitude-and-longitude-only-getting-0-0-0-0

Comment: @GauravADubey I posted an answer. Hopefully that can help.