# Getting "Source not found" error while trying to detect the location of an android device in my application

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have followed the following link to detect the location of a device in my program

[How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android).

But my application keeps giving the "Source not found" run time exception. Can anyone explain the reason behind it. I am also posting my code below:-

public void getLocation()
    {
        LocationManager locationmgr = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
Location location = locationmgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location_longitude = location.getLongitude();
        location_latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

};

locationmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

Comment: post you error  log. have you added access fine location permission

Comment: Yes I have added the permission. In fact I have added both the permission. And actually its not an error, but a runtime exception which reads "Source not found" @RachitaNanda

Answer (score 2):

I used this class and successfully finds user's current location . Hope it will works for you ...

```
public class LocationTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude


private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public LocationTracker(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation(){

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;

}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Log.d("lat", latitude+"");
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("long :", longitude+"");
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}


/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

and in your activity create the object of it and fetch location like as follows ....

```
LocationTracker locationTracker = new LocationTracker(StreamActivity.this);
if (!locationTracker.canGetLocation()) {
            locationTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        } else {

            latitude = locationTracker.getLatitude;
            longitude = locationTracker.getLongitude;


            locationTracker.stopUsingGPS();

        }
```

and add all the permissions in manifest file ....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

best of luck ....

Comment: It keeps throwing this source not found exception. Earlier it was throwing this exception while executing "requestlocationupdates()" and now after implementing the code provided by you, I am getting the same exception while "isProviderEnabled()" is getting executed. What could be the reason behind it? Am I missing out some libraries or something?? @Sachin

Comment: you can also go through this link [http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/] @zstart

Comment: Yes, the location service for my device is enabled. @Sachin

Comment: hey you go through above link . Check this demo is working in your device or not . It is successfully working for me . test it on device not on emulator @zstart

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing this code on a cell phone without a SIM card. Because I was using "GPS provider", I thought that it is not necessary to have a SIM card inserted on the device. But I was wrong. It worked like a charm on the device with a SIM card inserted.