# get Latitude and Longitude values from locationManager

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm trying to use Lat & Lon values for a function I created, but I can't find a way how to get this values from the class "Locationer" to the MainActivity.
I have created a new method called *getLat()*, but I need a location variable in order to get the latitude value with this method.
I have no idea how to get this "location" and where it comes from in the class.
I've am testing it on my own device.

The *Locationer* class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Locationer extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        String myLocation = "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude();

        //I make a log to see the results
        Log.e("MY CURRENT LOCATION", myLocation);

    }

    public double getLat(Location location)
    {
        return location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

the code in my MainAcitivity.java:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Locationer locationListener = new Locationer();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        lat = **NEED YOUR HELP TO GET THIS VALUE**
        lon = **NEED YOUR HELP TO GET THIS VALUE**

        queryBooks(lat, lon);
```

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You will have no latitude or longitude directly after setting the LocationManager. The onLocationChanged() will be called when it find a location. [See here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

You can do the `queryBooks(lat, lon);` in the `onLocationChanged()`.

Or you can use getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); but it will be less accurate and can provide you an old location.

Here what you can do in you MainActivity :

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        queryBooks(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }


};

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //every second
    int minTime = 1000;
    //minDistance between two update
    int minDistance = 10;
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, mLocationListener);
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: The question is if it's the best solution? I will have to move alot of my code to the location class and what happens if I will have multiple pages using the GPS system?

Comment: it's better to get the location in the onLocationChanged. To avoid move all your code in the Locationer class, just create the interface in your MainActivity

Comment: What do you mean by creating interface in the MainActivity? I already have one.