# Trouble finding current Location Android

Tags: android, location, sensors

How to get current latitude and Longitude without using any Google Api .I am new to Android coding So trying to get current lati longi but unable to get

Comment: First Try to Search in Google and then come over here if you face any issues...

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2227299/2752399

Comment: check this : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/