# How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in with android studio?

Tags: android

how to get the true Latitude and Longitude when a mobile device use the fake GPS for change Latitude and Longitude?

Comment: Have u tried anything .. you can post your implementation ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobile-device-in-android)

Comment: not duplicate. i mean  how to get the true Latitude and Longitude when a mobile device use fake GPS.

Comment: There will be no official way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code sample.

```
public class CurrentLocation {
Timer timer;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gpsEnabled=false;
boolean networkEnabled=false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult=result;
    if(locationManager ==null)
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try{
        gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{
        networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled)
        return false;

    if(gpsEnabled)
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(networkEnabled)
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer =new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

        Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
        if(gpsEnabled)
            gps_loc= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(networkEnabled)
            net_loc= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //if there are both values use the latest one
        if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
            if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            else
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }

        if(gps_loc!=null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            return;
        }
        if(net_loc!=null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }
        locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public void cancelTimer() {
    timer.cancel();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
}
    public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
```

}

Comment: thx for your sample code. i will tru it, sorry because I am newbie