# Get lat long only from network when Location setting is turned off

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to collect the `Latitude and Longitude` from user device.

There are multiple ways to do so. Right now am collecting the lat/lang from [`Google's API`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512926/3538065) <--- SO Answer.

Now there are also multiple methods in which they check the provider i.e either GPS OR Network Provider and collect the location using `LocationListener` and collect the data.

A sample code will be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535885/3538065) <--- Again a SO answer.

Both of them are working but my question is , what if the user has given the Location Permission and then turned of the `Location` service from settings. In that case I'll like to collect the lat/lang solely from the network provider.

But when I try the above codes after turning off the Location

[image] I get `null` as the location.

Every time the `requestLocationUpdates` returns a `null` location.

Basically I want a fall through options to collect the lat/long.

1-> Google Api (When location is on)
2-> LocationMangaer (When location is on)
3-> Get lat/lang from cellular tower (When location is off, wifi is off and GPS is off)

Comment: You can't get the network latlong unless GPS setting is turned on to `Battery Saving Mode` or else you can use `opencellid` API's

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about `opencellid` ?

Comment: Here is the [API details](http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/API), [FAQ](http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/FAQ) and [API Keys](http://opencellid.org/#action=database.requestForApiKey)

Comment: Thanks @MadhukarHebbar, but this is not what am looking for. It won't solve the purpose.

Comment: _"...my question is , what if the user has given the Location Permission and then turned of the Location service from settings."_ Then you can not determine the device's location. That's the whole idea of turning the Location service off. (Or maybe you can find the cell tower id and follow Madhukar's idea for getting a rough location. I'm not familiar with that myself.)

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;



locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (network_enabled) {
            getLocationDataByMobileNetwork();
        } else if (gps_enabled) {
            getLocationDataByGPS();
        }

private void getLocationDataByMobileNetwork() {
    try {
        appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getApplicationContext());
        Location nwLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (nwLocation != null) {
            latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"(Network):not fetched your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," (Network) in Exception:not fetched your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}



private void getLocationDataByGPS() {
    try {
        Location gpsLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (gpsLocation != null) {
            latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude(); 

        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

Comment: This returns `null` location when the location setting is turned off.