# How can I check permission in nonActivity Class?

Tags: android

I want to get current location in my app. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobile-device-in-android/6621161#6621161).

I have to check permission, but I cannot find how to check permission nonActivity class.

I tried this:

```
public class MyLocation {

    public MyLocation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {

        locationResult = result;
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);



        if (gps_enabled)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1 = new Timer();


        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(context), 10000);

        return true;
    }



    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        Context context;

        public GetLastLocation(Context context){
           this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Context context = getClass().getgetApplicationContext();
            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
    }

}
```

In my Activity I passed context;

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(this);
```

I am getting error in permission in GetLastLocation class ;

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
                                                                               Process: com.example.merve.myapplication, PID: 4124
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:439)
                                                                                   at other.MyLocation$GetLastLocation.run(MyLocation.java:124)
                                                                                   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
                                                                                   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

MyLocation.java line 124:

```
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I cannot add full code.

Comment: @sandy can you check my question, please.

Comment: You can pass the `context` to the non-activity class which you want to do the check. Use the `context` then in that class to call methods that require `context`

Comment: @Merka I edited my question

Comment: can you post the complete error log which tells the line number of the exception as well? Seems that the problem is you didn't initialize `context` field of  `GetLastLocation` class. It is `null` when used.

Comment: I fixed this problem according to  Leo Aso's answers. However, now I cannot open the app. There is no error, I can see lat and long in the console. @Merka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say this

```
    public GetLastLocation(Context context){
        context = this.context;
    }
```

should be

```
    public GetLastLocation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed this, but now cannot open the app. İn console, I can see latitude and longitude. An there is no error

Comment: When you say you can't open the app. do you mean it's crashing, or it's just not displaying anything? And , if it's crashing, is there a new error?

Comment: It is not displaying anything. finish() is the reason.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your activity or context object to the non-activity class.
The timertask doesn't run on the main thread so you have to ask for the permission somewhere else. Maybe before creating the GetLastLocation object

Comment: Do you have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your menifest?

Comment: Yes, I give the permission

Comment: I've up my answer